# Positive $a$, $b$, $c$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$, show $(2-a)(2-b)(2-c) \geq \frac{25}{27}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a;b;c>0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$
>
> Prove: $$(2-a)(2-b)(2-c) \geq \frac{25}{27}$$

I tried to use uvw method, but then  $$
(2−a)^2(2−b)≥25/27$$ with $$2a^2+b^2=3$$ is hard to finish by "paper and pencil"

Can anyone prove that problem without using Lagrange multipliers method?

Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to use uvw method, but then $(2-a)^2(2-b) \geq \dfrac{25}{27}$ with $2a^2+b^2=3$ is hard to finish by "paper and pencil"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A hint.** Suppose $c = \min \{a,\,b,\,c\}$ then $0 < c \leqslant 1.$

(1) Prove
$$(2-a)(2-b) \geqslant \frac{c^2+1}{2}.$$
(2) Find the minimum value of the expression
$$\frac{(2-c)(c^2+1)}{2}, \quad 0 < c \leqslant 1.$$

Comment: Đổi ảnh đại diện mới rồi à anh=))

Answer (score 0):

$WLOG$ $\min\left \{ a,b,c \right \}=c$ , then $0<c\le 1$.

**Claim 1**: $(2-a)(2-b)\ge \frac{c^2+1}{2}$.

**Claim 1** $\Leftrightarrow (2-a)(2-b)\ge \frac{4-a^2-b^2}{2}$

$\Leftrightarrow (a+b-2)^2\ge 0$ , which is obvious.

**Claim 2**: $\frac{(2-c)(c^2+1)}{2}\ge \frac{25}{27}$

Let $f(x)=(2-x)(x^2+1)=-x^3+2x^2-x+2$.

Then $f'(x)=-3x^2+4x-1=-(3x-1)(x-1)$.

So $f(c)\ge f(\frac{1}{3})=\frac{50}{27}\Rightarrow \frac{(2-c)(c^2+1)}{2}\ge \frac{25}{27}$.

Hence, we are done.

Comment: Isnt that essentially what the other answer says!?